# Aerospike Issue in reading data with header

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

I am facing an issue where aerospike read is stale .

Two thread is trying to update the record with generation id using operate API.

Thread 1 has updated the record and increased the generation id by one. verified this through reading the record again via Operate API. Wherein Thread2 read the same record with updated generation id (increased by Thread1) but the bins were not updated. How it is possible that generation id is changed but bins are not updated ? there are no other updates happened in between the operations ?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible since the record is held under lock during the transaction.

Is there any caching between the app and server?

Can you share the code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Application 1 is written in java and using the client I am reading the record updating the record and reading the record again from the operator API. Application2 is written in golang which is working on the same record. its does read the record via header api . update the record and read the record again from Operator API. Here application 1 has updated the record and applciation2 has read  with updated generation id but the record was not updated .

Comment: @kporter can you help me on this ?

Comment: @kporter anything here?

Comment: 1) Can you provide the client versions you are using (e.g. Java 5.1.9).
2) Can you provide the code for the update and read methods?
3) Are there any other apps updating these records?